# Break JAVA program from the Windows command prompt

Tags: java, console

I am running Windows 7. Is there any way to break a program running from the command prompt?

For example, I run a Java program that has multiple threads. In one of the threads, there is an exception, but the program continues to run.

I want to use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> command that I use for other programs, but for some reason this will not work. Any shortcuts to stop the program from the console?

Comment: It would probably be useful to include which operating system you are running this on.

Comment: @Exupery I'm assuming he's on Windows since he is using command prompt.

Comment: Does CTRL+C not work on Windows?

Comment: Yes, thank you! I never heard of CTRL+C always used CTRL+BREAK.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CTRL + C` to break the program.

Comment: and make sure you are hitting `CTRL+C`, for example, if your local keyboard is Dvorak (because you rock), and you remote into a machine which defaults to QWERTY (I know, right?), then you might not be sending what you think you're sending ...

Answer (score 0):

the first thing to do, you will have to write the code that you want to run and save that as a java executable file.

you should also make sure of proper intentions since as 'java' file and as a '.txt' file.
In other to do so, check here>> https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-prompt

now open the command prompt and run as administrator. make use of the 'cd' command to change the operating directory on the command prompt to the one you wat your java program is restored.

run the following command line:

```
cd Folder-destination [Java-program-flder]
```